# Laravel how to access public file after deploy the project on host

Tags: laravel

in my project I store pdf file as blob in the public/uploads folder via the move() function

```
$pdf->move(public_path('uploads/pdfs/'), $name)
```

but after I deploy the project on the host the project structure changed so all the public folders is inside the public_html and the whole rest project folder `project name` is in a folder inside the public_html too with the name of the project, so the uploads folder where I store the pdf files is beside the project folder, so when I try to store a pdf it creates whole new folder public/uploads/pdfs in the project folder but I need it to store the pdfs outside the project folder in the uploads folder, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

you could use a custom disk [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#on-demand-disks)

Or you can try to use 'path' instead 'public_path'.